# Bootstrap file upload input (without Javascript)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

well I know that this question was posted in similar style often enough, but one (in my opinion) critical point hasnt been adressed, is there a nice way to do this **without javascript**?
Especially on Mobile I have the experience that overscripted sites can have non-working buttons or similar stuff until the next refresh since the js broke (maybe because the internet is too slow, or a connection break whatever), so I want to do it without JavaScript, while retaining the ability to see the file name.

#### so long story short (TL;DR version)

- Style file input to look like bootstrap
- No Javascript
- Filename Display

is there a way to do this?

Comment: No .. You can try a plugin written for Bootstrap like, http://www.jasny.net/bootstrap/javascript/#fileinput

Comment: Post some work along, sometimes its needed.

Comment: it is not about work or no work, I have seen and used some js ways to get it working, but I am worried about what happens if the script gets killed. also you dont need to downvote it, I mean it is a legit question, I think. and there's also the point how js bahves with accessibility...
as I said there are enough places where I had to reload st least 25% of the tome to submit an js/AJAX form because the js broke on my Phone [Note 3 with Firefox], most notably we have WBB4 in this but even other places have this often enough)

Comment: @My1 it's getting downvoted because you didn't show any efford of solving your problem yourself. Add some snippet of you trying to solve your problem.

Comment: I did search for this but I found yet no way to display the file name without js there are also pure HTML/CSS tricks but no file name there either...

Comment: @My1 Because it can't be done without JS. The first two tasks however can be done, to create some "button" which opens the browsers "upload file" window.

Comment: well I'd actually have loved to ask that as a comment so I wouldnt have needed a question that gets downvoted, but I cant coz reputation, but instead of a simple "no it cant be done without js" I get 5 downvotes...
thanks for the info @vucko and consider your comment "upvoted"
also as I said in the comment before I have tried stuff like that but wanted a file name display and that's the sole reason for this question.

Comment: since I dont seem to be abler to edit my comment again, let's put another one., I think I did say clear enough both in the last words of the text and in the TLDR version that I wanted to know whether you could do an upload with file name display without js in bootstrap, this has not been asked answered or commented, and this isnt my first search for this so I dont think the question deserves downvoting

Comment: on hold because unclear what I ask? I think I summarized my stuff in the TLDR and hughlighted important stuff...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Done

```js
document.querySelector('#file').addEventListener('change', function() {
  var val = this.value.split(/\\/g);
  document.querySelector('#filename').innerHTML = val[val.length - 1];
});
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position:relative;  
  cursor:pointer;
  display:inline-block;
}

input {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  z-index:1;
  opacity:0;
  cursor:pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha256-MfvZlkHCEqatNoGiOXveE8FIwMzZg4W85qfrfIFBfYc= sha512-dTfge/zgoMYpP7QbHy4gWMEGsbsdZeCXz7irItjcC3sPUFtf0kuFbDz/ixG7ArTxmDjLXDmezHubeNikyKGVyQ==" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="wrapper">
  <input id="file" type="file" />  
  <span class="btn btn-primary btn-file">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-folder-open"></i>
    <span id="filename">Select File</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

2. Done.
3. It can't be done.

Comment: finally someone who just gives an answer without first nagging at the op.

by the way is there a hybrid-way, aka putting the file name in the button or alike if the user has a working js, but still not requiring js to make the styling work at all?
TLDR: if js -> make button text to file name, else -> just leave it styled

Comment: I was updated my code. I understand why you try to avoid to using JavaScript. Personally I prefer to use css only as much as I can. But I think that you don't need to worry about devices which not support JavaScript.

Comment: well I also try to understand CSS before I use it, but to be exact, understanding the input file is not that easy. I wonder why HTML5 didnt add any way to style this thing properly without js, since js just adds to the load of the connection and anything.
and even noscripts can be killed by it since if the browser knows that it has js enabled it wont use the noscript stuff but if somehow the js crashes, I'm left with a non-functional UI but your code looks nice.

Comment: okay we have problems: 1) TypeError: document.querySelector(...) is null 2) the input expands over the whole page (thou invisible, so any click throws the file dialog, making the page unusable. I am trying to throw some stuff together, look a bit like this: take your js, throw your css and use this for HTML
```
<label class="btn btn-primary" for="file">
  <input id="file" type="file" style="display:none" />  
    <i class="fa fa-lg fa-file"></i> <!-- fontawesome-->
    <span id="filename">Select File</span>
</label>
```
but even using your version directly throws the error

Comment: 1. You have to set the input id as `file` and only him. 2. I was updated the code (add to `.wrapper` `position:relative`, so the button will only clickable.

Comment: well it's kinda obvious that the input id needs to be file and only for that element (not counting comments)

Comment: okay problem solved, I put the script in before, but seems that the script must come AFTER the content.

Comment: posted my stuff as edit, I improved it a bit with the other stuff I found.

Comment: and another one. now we have label, almost no css (a `display:none` as inline style has to remain), button behavior and a shortened file name.